# How do I retrieve the client using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, socket.io, passport.js

I am trying to make a live chat platform, but I am not sure how to get the user who sent the message.

Here is my code (No errors)

```js
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  console.dir(socket)
)}
```

### All help is appreciated!

*( Also, this is my first post, so please tell me if I am doing something wrong (: )*

Comment: I found out that I could use IP addresses, but they sometimes change if they are dynamic.